# Similarity and difference between Archimedian and non-Archimedian geometry

Tags: non-archimedean-fields

This question is on similarity and difference between Archimedian and non-Archimedian field. 
An example of non-Archimedian field is the field of $p$-adic numbers $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

We have concept of continuity in $\mathbb{Q}_p$, since there is $p$-adic norm, we have also concept of differentiation in $\mathbb{Q}_p$. We can define inner product in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ as a vector space.

> We say in non-Archimedian field any triangle is isoscale  due to $-adic norm and every point in a sphere is its centre both of which differs from Euclidean geometry and Archimedian field.

So if I ask-

**Does there exist concept of angles, ray between two lines over non-Archimedian field  as in our ordinary Euclidean Geometry** ?

**Edit:** This was my first post in this forum instead of mathstackexchange.com, by mistake, long ago. This is not a research question but purely for knowledge purpose and for curiosity. I am just editing it to develop the question to give a sense so that it becomes suitable.

Comment: What would a line segment be?

Comment: I am not sure about a line segment. But if I consider the Non-archimedian field of $ Q-adic \ numbers \ $ , which is a completion of the rational field $ \ \mathbb{Q} \ $ So irrational numbers (sequence of rationals) also is in the field $ \ \mathbb{Q}_p \ $.

Comment: I'll mention that (geometry) tag is deprecated - see [the tag-info](https://mathoverflow.net/tags/geometry/info). Although I am not exactly sure which geometry related tag to choose instead.

Comment: The nonarchimedean fields are really not geometric in the sense that you want to think of geometry. Never say never, but I don’t think that this is a productive direction to go in.

Comment: Yes sir. But can I imagine about a geometric figure in non-archimedian field which was in Euclidean geometry . Example; All triangles in Non-archimedian field or geometry are isoscales in metric sense

Comment: See also: ultrametric space https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrametric_space

Comment: I think that there is some confusion.  An irrational number is not a sequence of rationals; it is the *limit* of a sequence of rationals.  Since the notion of 'limit' depends on the topology, a sequence does not determine 'the same' irrational number in $\mathbb Q_p$ as in $\mathbb R$. … (1/2)

Comment: … Thus, for example, one cannot ask about "the number $\pi$ in $\mathbb Q_p$", because the sequence $3, 3.1, 3.14, 3.141, …$ (or whatever you like) converges in $\mathbb R$ (or one can say:  is Cauchy in the Archimedean metric on $\mathbb Q$), but not in any $\mathbb Q_p$.

Comment: @LSpice Concerning "whatever you like", it's actually quite the opposite: for any $x\in\mathbb Q_p$, there is a rational sequence that converges to $\pi$ in $\mathbb R$, and converges to $x$ in $\mathbb Q_p$. (There's nothing special about $\pi$ here, of course. And it also holds with a bunch of $\mathbb Q_{p_i}$'s simultaneously.)

Comment: @EmilJeřábek, I guess you were pointing out that one doesn't have total freedom in the choice of rational sequence approximating $\pi$ in $\mathbb R$, right?  I was just trying to emphasise that there was nothing particularly special about the approximating sequence I chose, but of course you are right that I inadvertently overstated my case.  (Your "a bunch" means "(up to) all but one", right?  [Burger and Struppeck - Does $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty 1/n!$ really converge?](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2974669) is my favourite exposition of this.)

Comment: @LSpice Actually, I think it works for “all”. That is, $\mathbb Q$ is dense in the topological product $\mathbb R\times\prod_p\mathbb Q_p$. IIRC the “all but one” formulation is needed for the adele ring $\mathbb A_\mathbb Q$, whose topology is finer than the one inherited from the topological product.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek, not only are you correct, but it is Theorem 1 (p. 569) of the article I linked, so I should have known it!  Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I do not know much about $q$-adic numbers, so there might be something wrong with my attempt.

I think that you could try to do analytic geometry, but with q-adic number coordinates rather than real, and see what works and what fails. My thoughts:

- Squared distance between $a=(x_1,y_1)$ and $b=(x_2,y_2)$ is $(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2$ -- this makes perfect sense in $q$-adic numbers.
- Distance is harder, because you would need to take the root of squared distance, and roots are not guaranteed to exist in $q$-adic numbers.
- A line passing through $a$ and $b$ is the set of points of form $ta+(1-t)b$. Again, this makes perfect sense.
- However, you cannot define a line segment, as it requires ordering.
- You could define a triangle as a shape that has three vertices, and consists of three lines between these three vertices. Similarly you could define an $n$-gon. Just as there is no concept of a line segment, there is also no concept of inside/outside of such shape, but you can still define a boundary.
- Inner and cross products can be defined just as usual.
- We know that the inner product of vectors $v$ and $w$ equals $<v,w> = |v| \cdot |w| \cdot \cos \alpha$. Thus, we can define the squared cosine of the angle between two vectors: $(\cos \alpha)^2 = <v,w>^2 / |v|^2 |w|^2$. If the values of $(\cos\alpha)^2$ for two angles are different, then the angles cannot be equal. Unfortunately, this gives no way to tell the angle $\alpha$ from $-\alpha$, so we cannot add or subtract such angles.
- We could also define angles as points $(x,y)$ such that $x^2+y^2=1$. The angle between vectors $v$ and $w$ is $a$ iff $w\sim va$, where $d$ is a $q$-adic number, the multiplication $va$ works as in complex numbers (i.e., (1,0)(1,0)=(1,0), (0,1)(1,0)=(0,1), and (0,1)(0,1)=(-1,0)), and $\sim$ is vector colinearity defined as $(x_1,y_1)\sim(x_2,y_2)$ iff $x_1/x_2=y_1/y_2$ or $y_1=y_2=0$. The points $(x,y)$ and $(-x,-y)$ are the same angle (i.e., actually, angles are equivalence classes $\{(x,y), (-x,y)\}$), but this is not a problem since we use only lines, not line segments. Such angles can be added (complex multiplication) or negated (complex conjugate).

I do not know what you mean by "any triangle in an Non-archimedian field is Isoscale triangle" -- at least this does not seem to be the case with the above.

Comment: Yes in archimedian field there is an ultrametric and with respect to that metric every triangle becomes isoscale triangle.

Comment: Your squared distance can vanish, or be a non-square!

Comment: Much of what you say makes sense over any field, such as your definition of line. Distance is no good, unless you’re willing to consider the set of all points $X$ that are at zero distance from a given $P$. Rather you should make use of the absolute value on $\Bbb Q_q$ that is already inherent there. You should define a triangle just by its vertices, and forget about lines between the vertices. There’s no way of defining angles: for one thing, there’s really no cosine function. The $p$-adic world really is different from the real world.

Comment: Also, the usual meaning of "any triangle in a non-Archimedean field is isosceles" is that, if the vertices of the notional 'triangle' are drawn from the field itself (rather than from the plane over that field), and the distances between them are measured according to the metric (as a real numbers, not elements of the $p$-adic field), then two of those distances will be equal.

Comment: @Lubin Well, the usual power series gives a fairly well-behaved cosine function defined on a neighbourhood of $0$ in $\mathbb Q_q$.

Comment: How to get the some parallel problem for my Ph.D. purpose in this Non-archimedian Geometry or field? Can you help me

Comment: Of course, @EmilJeřábek, there is a series, convergent on the same small disk that the exponential function is. It’s not clear that it does much for you, though.